# How to run meteor iOS app with localhost (not with live server)?

Tags: android, ios, meteor

My project is deployed on live server; I want to make some customization, but it's live, so I am having same backup on Mac and doing customization. I just put this code (`meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=http://localhost:3000 --production`) in `run-mobile.sh` and I ran the same command (`meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=http://localhost:3000 --production`) in meteor directory.

My application is getting open in Xcode simulator and running well, but I am unable to see my customized code: it's still showing codes coming from server, but I want to run the iOS app with localhost, not with live server.

Does there need to be any other file, or do I need to change that file which I did not find? If so, where I can found that to set localhost?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute just `meteor run ios-device`, it starts a local meteor server and opens Xcode. No need for the `--mobile-server` option.

You also don't need the `--production` option. According to the meteor help, it's just to:

```
Simulate production mode. Minify and bundle CSS and JS files.
```